# NullPointerException in java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.isDelimiter

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jvm, tiff, javax.imageio

Sometimes I'm getting a NullPointerException in
java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.isDelimiter
but I can't reproduce this consistently.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.isDelimiter(Unknown Source), 
java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.scanToken(Unknown Source), 
java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.countTokens(Unknown Source), 
com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFField.createFromMetadataNode(TIFFField.java:476), 
com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.parseIFD(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1576), 
com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.mergeNativeTree(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1600), 
com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.mergeTree(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1624), 
java.desktop/javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata.setFromTree(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using this line:

```
// metaData is of type: javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata
// node is of type: org.w3c.dom.Node
// formatName has value: "com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_image_1.0";

metaData.setFromTree(formatName, node);
```

Could this be a bug in the JVM?
I'm using Adopt OpenJDK OpenJ9 11.0.4

Comment: It could, but it is extremely unlikely. You don't get the problem if you process the same file multiple times? Can you isolate it so that you can run the command for one file from the command line and get the error? You will need a reproducible minimal example for a bug report anyway.

Comment: It's more likely a bug in the JDK source code than the JVM... But in any case it's very odd. Looking at the source code, `StringTokenizer` is used only for parsing `TIFFUndefined` values, which is represented by a string of comma separated byte values. What does your `node` tree look like? Can you export it as XML and include it here?

Comment: If you are seeing inconsistent results when reading the same file, I would suspect a multi-threading problem.   Are you using `ImageIO.read`, or are you explicitly obtaining an ImageReader and using the same ImageReader in multiple threads?

Comment: When the package `com.sun.media.imageio.plugins` does not original from the JDK provided plugin, as the stacktrace suggests, does that mean that you’re intentionally using a different TIFF plugin?

Comment: @Holger Good catch! That seems to be the JAI TIFF plugin. The OpenJDK TIFF plugin is based on the same code IIRC, but there could some slight differences. AND: If you have both the JAI and the JDK plugin installed, and don't set an explicit order, they could potentially be selected at random... Might be related to the inconsistent behavior the OP experiences.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the replies so far. Yes I am using multiple threads and this is where I currently suspect where the cause of the issue lies. I also added logging for the node object, so it becomes visible what's wrong with it. Also I am using the jai_core.jar libraries along with the JDK that I'm using. As soon as I know more I will reply again.